# How to make ffmpeg cmd run if there is space in director path or file name

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I am using ffmpeg to cut video via android, all working fine but only issue come when if the source directory contain space the command is not working by saying file not found

```
-i /storage/emulated/0/ISave Videos/Br0gv9anKKg.mp4 -acodec copy -vcodec copy -ss 00:00:10 -t 00:00:20 /storage/emulated/0/1547813275685ChunkClip.mp4
```

file not found is Like"File not found -i /storage/emulated/0/ISave"

But for other path no issue and all works fine only if space is there in file path the issue comes

Comment: Quote the patch: `"/storage/emulated/0/ISave Videos/Br0gv9anKKg.mp4"`

Comment: No dude i tried all but not working, but the following solution worked, Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cool Question

Its very confusing to solve there type of issues even if we get a solution
The following Link show some fix for handling issues like this
[Quoting and escaping](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#Quoting-and-escaping)

So for the issue you have there is fix Add each word in  ffmpeg comments to an LinkedList and then convert to command array so that ffmpeg will execute it

As follows (As per you requirement command)

```
List<String> cmdList = new LinkedList<>();
                cmdList.add("-i");
                cmdList.add("/storage/emulated/0/ISave Videos/Br0gv9anKKg.mp4");
                cmdList.add("-acodec");
                cmdList.add("copy");
                cmdList.add("-vcodec");
                cmdList.add("copy");
                cmdList.add("-ss");
                cmdList.add("00:00:10");
                cmdList.add("-t");
                cmdList.add("00:00:20");
                cmdList.add("/storage/emulated/0/1547813275685ChunkClip.mp4");

String[] command  = cmdList.toArray(new String[cmdList.size()]);
```

Hope your issue will be get resolved by this solution

Comment: Thanks dude it worked, finaly ur solution heleped me